# Nested/child collections filtering in Entity Framework (ver. 1 or 4)

Tags: .net, entity-framework

How to filter nested/child collections of entities when including them in EF?

Example:
Let's have standard Customer-Orders association. How to load all customers and include only their last three orders in their Orders collection?

Is there something like [AssociateWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882678.aspx) function from L2S for EF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unfortunately the Object Services API in Entity Framework doesn't expose a way to selectively load associated entities based on a condition.

One way to solve this problem is to filter the associated entities when projecting the results in a query:

```
context.Customers.Select(c => new
    {
        Customer = c,
        LastOrders = c.Orders
                         .OrderByDescending(o => o.CreatedDate)
                         .Take(3)
                         .ToArray()
    }
```

Related resources:

- [Loading Related Objects (Entity Framework)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272(v=VS.100).aspx)

Comment: Add `.ToList().Select(c => c.Customer)` and you have what you wanted. Every customer will have only 3 last orders in `Orders` entity collection, but only if you didn't load orders earlier in the same context. No need to define additional type and use anonymous classes.